# How to convert char[] to char* in C?

Tags: c, type-conversion

The question is pretty straightforward. How do I convert a `char[]` to a `char*` in C?
I'm really having a hard time finding the solution for it. So your help is highly appreciated :)

Here is why I need this:

```
sprintf(name,"%c%c%%HACKED%c%c.virus",a,b,c,d); // print a formatted text to string (char[])
strcat(buffer,currentPath); // currentPath is of data type char[]
strcat(buffer,"\\");
strcat(buffer,name); // Now this is where the problem comes in. Since strcat function needs a const char* for it's second argument.

printf("%s",name);
```

Comment: Doesn't it work? I mean, the last `strcat`? I'd be surprised. `name` is a real char[], yes? You didn't include its definition. Otherwise, the `printf` would fail too.

Comment: Pro Tip: Avoid naming your viruses with the extension .virus.

Comment: You know, brain activation fail. I just saw “string const, whatever,” didn't even process the English meaning of contents. Perhaps I should be *advocating* the use of `strcat` and some sketchy pointer math :-) ++@aardvarkk

Comment: @aardvarkk : Haha, actually it's just a test project of mine to tinker with the language. This program creates an infinite loop that will fill the hard drive with files (having really big file size). So the extension is not really that important. At least for now. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to do anything. The array automatically decays into the pointer, so your code appears fine.

You do need to make sure that `buffer` starts off with a valid, NUL-terminated string before you call `strcat()` for the first time. It also needs to be writeable (it can't, for example, be a pointer to a string literal).

You also need to make sure you don't overflow `buffer`. I'd recommend you look into [`strncat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/strncat.html).

Comment: Well, I read the OP's "this is where the problem comes in" as "I get a compiler error here".

Comment: strncat() is a bad advise. Always.

Comment: Thanks! Silly me.. I just overflowed the buffer and that's why it didn't worked on my end.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the code has declared the buffers with something like:

```
     char buffer[100];
     char name[100];
```

Not part of your question, but *don't use `strcat`* in new code. Never. Check out `strncat`. It's *really dangerous* and `strncat` is not (as much).

As for your direct question: You can just use `name` as though it were a `char*`. The C compiler will automatically convert that into (the logical equivalent of) `&(name[0])`.

Comment: `strcat` is just as dangerous. `strncpy`, `sprintf`, etc, all potential segfaults.

Answer (score 1):

BTW why the silly strcat() thing? why not:

```
sprintf(name,"%c%c%%HACKED%c%c.virus",a,b,c,d);
sprintf(buffer,"%s\\\\%s", currentPath, name );

     /* should this be printf("%s", buffer); ?? */
printf("%s",name);
```

And, as BPRcock says: snprintf() is even better.

Comment: Or just `sprintf(buffer, %s\\%c%c%%GEHAKT%c%c.virus",currentPath,a,b,c,d);`

Comment: Yes sure, but it could be that the OP had special plans with the name part.

Answer (score 1):

In C, the value of an object of type `char [N]` is converted to a value of `char *` type.

```
void *p;
char a[16] = {0}

p = a;
```

in the expression statement `p = a;` the value `a` is of type `char *`.

> (C99, 6.3.2.1p3) "Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type "array of type" is converted to an expression with type "pointer to type" that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue."